# Bootstrap navbar disappears after click on hamburger iPhone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

so I am working on this page, and I'm designing the mobile version and I came across a problem. When I click on the hamburger menu on my iPhone the navbar where the navbar-brand and the hamburger menu is disappears. I can't collapse the hamburger, it's just hidden. The dropdown also is not in the right position, it overflows to the top of the page.

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navBar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand minecraftFont" href="#" style="font-size: 18px; margin-top: 4px;">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logoFilter" style="width: 45px;" alt="">
        RayCraft
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#raycraft-navbar" aria-controls="raycraft-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobileNavbar" id="raycraft-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item font-17">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Store</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item font-17">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Servers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item font-17">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item font-17">
            <a class="nav-link navLink" href="#">Rules</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="d-flex justify-content-sm-end justify-content-center align-items-center darkmodeLi">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center darkmode" style="width: 40px; height: 100%;">
              <svg>
                <path />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">English</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <div id="toHun" class="dropdown-item langButtons">Magyar</div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image: Navbar showing]
[image: Clicked hamburger]

As you can see, if I click on the hamburger button, the navbar shows, but in a horribly wrong position. I tried adding margin to .mobileNavbar (collapse navbar-collapse) and I got the following result.

[image: With margin]

As we can see the position is now okay, but the navbar is still not showing, and on android it looks very bad.

On desktop in Chrome with developer options, selecting the iPhone X resolution the site looks like this:

[image: Desktop mobile version]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Provide minimal working example please. Without it I can only recommend you to connect iPhone with USB cable to your PC and use remote debugging. Tutorial: **https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/**. There is always some minor issues for cross-browser compatibility and this is the fastest way to debug it.

Comment: what information would you like to know? i don't understand, sry

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you have. So we can replicate your problem on our devices. Paste your code there with proper version of Bootstrap so we can see result of your code. **Minimal working example** is part of your code that is functional itself, but contains only parts, that is relevant to your question.